# Raster Calculator in QGIS returns -3.4e10^38 when saved

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, null

I'm using the raster calculator with the following formula: `"myraster"@1-100`

Now if I choose the option save as tiff file the resulting raster consists of cells with value -3.4e10^38 (negative float-max). If I save it as a temporary file the resulting raster returns the correct cell values.

Does anybody know why that is?

Comment: Can you share a tiny raster that reproduces this?

Comment: If you save the temporary raster to tiff what happens?

Comment: When I save the temporary raster to tiff QGIS crashes after a while (at around 13 Gbyte). When I save a fraction of the extent it works.

Comment: Also when I continue to work with the temporary file the following calculations return wrong results.

Comment: Sounds like you have nodata values? QGIS seems to have problems with nodata values if you use raster calculator with temporary layers.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? I have a similar issue even with rasterio. The file (.tiff) which I use is large.